# ERRO with PYTHON: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects

Tags: python, scripting, ftplib

I try to connect to an ftp server with the login method of the ftplib module but it throws this error:

```
File "conect.py", line 12, in (module)
  cod= conection.login(us, pa)
File "C:\Python27\lib\ftplib.py", line 394, in login
  resp = self.sendcmd('USER ' + user)
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects
```

The script that I try to execute is the following:

```
from ftplib import FTP

ip = raw_input("Enter ip: ")
user = open("usss.txt","r") 
passw = open("passs.txt","r")

us = user.readlines()
pa = passw.readlines()


conection = FTP(ip)
state_ftp = conection.login(us, pa)
print state_ftp
print "[+]CONECTION SUCCESSFUL!"
```

I do not understand why it says that I am concatenating a string with a list if I have not delcared any list.

Does anyone know where the problem is?

Comment: Here's a hint: what type is the output of `user.readlines()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`user.readlines()` returns a list of lines.

As a result, `us` and `pa` are both lists, and the types are incompatible.

To get the whole file, use `us.read()`

Comment: Thanks Bro. I will try